# GET Requests scripts not generated in Vugen load runner

Tags: load, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a doubt whether load runner does't record the GET requests ? however POST

method in-turn get requests are recorded.

But specifically load runner doesn't capture GET requests as separate custom

request or any ? Am using mobile HTTP/HTML protocol.

Can anybody please clarify that for mobile HTTP/HTML protocol , load runner will

record GET requests separately or not ? Because in my native app I can see that

only GET requests are not recorded.

Thanks,

Prabhakar.Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadRunner captures all HTTP requests, including GET ones. Are you recording a business process on a mobile device? Which recording technique are you using (proxy, traffic analysis etc.)?

Comment: @ Gal Shadeck,  yes am recording business process on mobile device and recording technique is proxy. I obeserved that only POST requests scripts are generated in vugen. But the GET requests business process scripts are not generated. What would be the reaosn ? Is their any other setting which needs to be done ? Can you give  your thoughts.

Comment: I put forth a hypothesis based upon your using an APP, that the resource objects are local to the app and therefore no GET is required.  By extension your application only needs to POST for the dynamic portions of the content rather than interface objects

Comment: @Gal Shadeck, I changed the recording type as "URL mode" then I was able to see the GET Requests. Thanks